# How can I make my articles readable on smartphones reader?

Tags: html, mobile, markup

When I browse on websites with my iPhone, sometimes I get an icon at the top left corner. When I tap it, I get the whole article without all the ads and other stuff on a plain white background.

The HTML in my example screenshot has no special markup - so I guess Safari is smart enough to get the right content.

[image: Screenshot of website in Safari and readable feature of Safari]

But is it possible to support such browser features? How are they called and how do they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader), you only have to wrap your text with HTML tag. The `<article>` element works fine as a wrapper; Safari Reader recognizes it. It doesn’t matter which wrapper element you choose, as long as there is one, other than `<body>` or `<p>`. You can use `<article>`, `<div>`, `<section>`

Your text should be long enough (100 words) with at least five child elements inside the wrapper. Inside a `<p>`-tag every `<br/>`-tag cuts your chapter in two chapters.

Answer (score -3):

try to make everything reponsive. For example use % for your width not px or pc

Comment: Regarding to the article Simon M. posted in the comments, I doubt that it has something to do with responsive design.

Answer (score -3):

you can try to make your sites responsive with Bootstrap(http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/)

an other way to make sites responsive is by using media query's
(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

I hope this helps you with creating responsive articles

Comment: I am using Bootstrap, but this is not my question. My website is responsive, but I want to know what markup I have to use to get the right text and pictures into Safaris Reader.